# django-tables2: set attrs for many columns?

Tags: python, css, django, django-tables2

I have a django-tables2 Table with many columns. Hence, I don't want to specify each column in the Table class separately, but just set the Model correspondingly.

Now, I'd like to change the properties of some columns that I can identify via their name. I'd like to do something like:

```
table = MyTable(my_queryset)

for col in table.columns.items():
    col_name = col[0]
    if col_name.endswith('some_suffix'):
        table.columns[col_name].attrs['td'].update({'align': 'right'})
```

... which was supposed to change all columns whose name end with `'some_suffix'` such that the values are aligned right.

The problem, however, seems to be that `table.columns[col_name]` is a `BoundColumn` whose properties apparently can't be altered.

Does anyone know a quick fix for this problem ("make selected columns right aligned")?

Thank you,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, not being able to change the attributes of the bound columns. This question seems to be the only one at SO to address this problem.

Besides `table.columns` there is also a property `table.base_columns`. In the second the columns aren't yet bound. So here is my approach:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class YourTable(tables.Table)
    # define your columns

    # overload the init method
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for col in self.base_columns:
            if col[0].endswith('some_suffix'):
                col[1].attrs['td'].update({'align': 'right'})
        # very important! call the parent method
        super(YourTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The changes now will be saved, because they are made in the base columns before they are bound. Calling the parent method - overloading the `__init__` method - binds them and the changes are visible in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to do such things is to create the table dynamically (i.e create a `Table` class using pythons `type` and set its fields). I am describing this technique (to solve a different problem) in this article: http://spapas.github.io/2015/10/05/django-dynamic-tables-similar-models/

What I propose in that article, is to create a `get_table_class` method that will create the Table subclass. In your case, it could be something like this:

```
def get_table_class(model):
      def get_table_column(field):
          if field.name.endswith('some_suffix'):
              return tables.Column(attrs={"td": {"align": "right"}})
          else:
              return tables.Column()

      attrs = dict(
          (f.name, get_table_column(f)) for
          f in model._meta.fields if not f.name == 'id'
      )
      attrs['Meta'] = type('Meta', (), {'attrs':{"class":"table"}, "order_by": ("-created_on", ) } )
      klass = type('DTable', (tables.Table, ), attrs)

      return klass
```

The `attrs = dict(...)` line above creates a dictionary containing all the field names of the model that you pass to it (except the id field) as keys and corresponding `Table` columns (using your suffix check to align them through `get_table_column`) as values. The `attrs['Meta'] = ...` line adds a `Meta` to this dictionary (as you can see the model attribute is no longer needed) and finally the `klass = type...` line creates a `Table` subclass using the above dictionary!